# How to move all files inside present subfolders up here

Tags: shell, command-line, file-management

I have 50 folders with some subfolders too, with more than 1000 audio files total. I need to remove all subfolders and put all files in present level. Tried `mv */* ./` but it complaints: argument list too long

Answer (score 7):

I assume that your audio files extention is .mp3

```
find <AudioFolderPath> -name '*.mp3' -exec mv -it <YourTargetFolder> {} +
```

### Notes:

- Replace `.mp3` with your audio files extention
- Replace `<AudioParentFolderPath>` with the parent folder that content your subfolders.
- Replace  `<YourTargetFolder>` with the folder path that you need to put all files in.
- If tow files from different subfolders have the same name **only one will be moved.**

**edit :** As [Costas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182442/83339) said :
  "The `-i` switch makes `mv` interactive, it will prompt before overwriting existing files"

Comment: does '-t' allow you to specify the destination first? (as I don't have this option on my "mv" here, I can only assume so as you put first the destination folder and then the list of files to move there... but if not, this will try to fit all in the last filename, giving out a warning) `t` could be for "target" ?

Comment: Yes as you said , `-t` allow to specify the destination first . 
from the `mv` manual page :

`-t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY`
            

`move all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY`

Comment: please note that this is GNU mv's option, and not available on every unices (in some production environment, at least). I provide a more portable solution, but yours works fine for Linux

Comment: yes @OlivierDulac, you are right,thanks for your note.

Answer (score 5):

```
find . -type f -mindepth 2 -exec mv -t ./ {} +
```

Note that that command will overwrite any files with the same name. You can use this to be prompted before overwriting:

```
find . -type f -mindepth 2 -exec mv -it ./ {} +
```

#### Explanation

- `-type f` : only find regular files.
- `-mindepth 2` : find only files in subdirectories.
- `-exec mv -it ./ {}`: the `-exec` means "run this *command* on every file found". The `{}` will be replaced with the file names. The `-i` switch makes `mv` interactive, it will prompt before overwriting existing files and the `-t` sets the target directory to `./`.
- `+` : put files together (in one argument line) so many as shell can operate with *command* to invoke *command* minimum times (not one by one but one to several).

Regarding futher empty folder deletions you can use same recepie:

```
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

Comment: `-type f` selects only plain files, excluding symbolic links, named pipes and the like. To move all files other than directories you can do `! -type d`.

Comment: @jimmij I suppose nobody store audio-files as named pipe or something else. If you worry about symlinks you can use `-L` parameter

Comment: `-i` is standard, `-t` is GNU-only (nothing to do with Linux which is just a kernel found in some GNU and non-GNU systems)

Comment: I concur with @StéphaneChazelas : `-t` doesn't exist on some systems (like a not-so-ancient AIX)

Comment: @OlivierDulac It is almost impossible to find decision to satisfy everybody so the different variants are welcome. Nobody prohibit you to change string to `find . -type f -mindepth 2 -exec mv {} ./ \;`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's a limit on the cumulative size of arguments and environment passed to the `execve()` system call when executing an external command.

With `zsh`, you can use its builtin `mv` instead:

```
zmodload -F zsh/files +b:zf_mv
zf_mv ./*/* .
```

Or use `zargs` to break the list into manageable chunks:

```
autoload zargs
zargs -Ifiles ./*/* -- mv files .
```

With `ksh93`:

```
command -x mv ./*/* .
```

With GNU `xargs` and with GNU `mv` with a shell where `printf` is builtin (most, `mksh` being the notable exception):

```
printf '%s\0' ./*/* | xargs -r0 mv -t .
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that OP want to move only files, not directories, so you need to take care of that. In `zsh` case you can put some *glob qualifiers*, e.g. `(.)` or `(^/)` after last `*`.

Answer (score 0):

A quite portable solution could be :

find all files in every subfolders, and move them in the current dir

```
find ./*/ -type f -print | xargs mv -i "{}" ./
```

You can add a `| egrep "\.au$|\.mp3$|\.ac3$"` in between to also ensure the files you found are files with an audio extension (add as many extension as necessary to cover all type, I just provide 3 common ones)

Comment: In your case there is no need to call `find` at all. Just enough `echo` or `printf`

Comment: @Costas: the OP mention there are so many files that "*" can't be expanded ... Here I just expand the 50 folders names, and the rest is handled by xargs

Comment: But `find` do not settle the problem but `xargs` do.